# Are the ten commandments considered part of the old testament law?

Tags: mosaic-law, ten-commandments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply)

Leviticus contains many laws that modern-day Christians do not follow. From what I've understood, this is because they consider this law to have been fulfilled through the death of Christ. However, they also often tout the ten commandments as a source of morality.

Were the ten commandments not part of the law that was fulfilled? Or is there some other reason why Christians still adhere to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ten Commandments are also refered to as the decalogue.  However, Christians do not believe that the death and resurrection of Jesus were the fulfillment of the Ten Commandments, it was the life of Jesus Christ that was because He alone was able to live a holy life within the parameters of the Ten Commandments.

However, Christians today often "tout" the Ten Commandments because they have more or less become an icon of Judeo-Christian morality seeing as the 613 commandments in the OT are built upon them.  *But according to the first half of Romans 8, the Christian life is less about living by the Law of God and more about living by the Spirit of God.*

Yet an even more concise manner of living by the Ten Commandments can be seen as following the two greatest commandments, to love God and neighbor seen here in [Matthew 22:36-40 NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2022:36-40&version=NIV):

> <sup>36</sup>“Teacher, which is the greatest commandment in the Law?”
>   <sup>37</sup>Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ <sup>38</sup> This is the first and greatest commandment. <sup>39</sup>And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ <sup>40</sup> All the Law and the Prophets hang on
>      these two commandments.”

I hope this helps!