# If "Old Law is done away with",then what about bestiality and incest?

Tags: mosaic-law, sexuality, law-and-gospel, animals, incest

Leviticus 18:7 states:

"Do not violate your father by having sexual relations with your mother. She is your mother; you must not have sexual relations with her."

**Isn't saying that the old law is "done away with" by logic, giving an excuse to say that people can now have sex with their mother?**

Leviticus 18:23 states: “A man must not defile himself by having sex with an animal. And a woman must not offer herself to a male animal to have intercourse with it. This is a perverse act.

**If the old law is "done away with" then doesn't this also mean by logic, that bestiality is now okay?**

Comment: Would all denominations have the same view on this? I think that might not be the case.

Comment: Welcome Keith. Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for this site: we don't attempt to discover the truth, *per se*, but rather our goal is to objectively describe and learn what specific groups of Christians believe. If you'd like to narrow the question by asking for the view of a particular denomination, this question may be answerable.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: This is basically a more specific version of [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/456/21576)  Most of Christendom is probably going to agree that the answer to this question is "no," but different traditions are going to explain "why not" differently.  So that's why we need you to specify: Roman Catholicism, Covenant theology, Theonomy, etc.

Comment: I think it's okay to assume that bestiality and incest are NOT okay things. But ya know.

Comment: @NealC We don't answer whether things are OK. We answer whether groups of Christians believe and teach that things are OK.

Comment: @MattGutting That is why I wrote a comment, NOT an answer.

Comment: it is best to look at life through God's word, there we can know what is right and wrong, what is good and what is evil. Opinions of others (even other Christians) shouldn't dictate what we believe over God's Word.