# Should a Christian wear clothing of mixed fibers?

Tags: sin, leviticus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply)
>   [How should a christian evaluate whether a particular action a sin or not?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/how-should-a-christian-evaluate-whether-a-particular-action-a-sin-or-not)

I hear Leviticus 19:19 brought up from time to time, mainly because it's one in a laundry list of sins. It states:

> Ye shall keep my statutes. Thou shalt not let thy cattle gender with a diverse kind: thou shalt not sow thy field with mingled seed: neither shall a garment mingled of linen and woolen come upon thee.

If a sin is a sin is a sin, where does wearing mixed fibers fall in the grand scheme? Is this something that all Christians should honor?

Comment: Duplicate of either : [How should a christian evaluate whether a particulare action is a sin or not?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/how-should-a-christian-evaluate-whether-a-particular-action-a-sin-or-not) or [What is the essence of sin?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-is-the-essence-of-sin)

Comment: Could also be a dupe of http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply or http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30/how-is-ignoring-clear-biblical-instructions-in-leviticus-justified or http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15/do-we-have-to-obey-the-laws-of-the-bible-if-so-what-laws

Answer (score 3):

As has been stated in answer to other such questions, God made covenants with Noah, Abraham, Israel, etc.  The Mosaic Law is a specific covenant between God and the Jewish people.  This covenant included many things, including the prohibition of wearing clothing with mixed fibers.  This covenant was enacted about 3500 years ago, I think.  Isaiah spoke of a new covenant that was enacted when Jesus died and rose again.  So, the Mosaic covenant was in effect between God and the Jewish nation for about 1500 years, but it is in effect no more.

Certainly, animal sacrifices are no longer required in the new covenant, because Jesus was offered once for all time.

So, for Jewish people living  between 1500 B.C. and about 30 A.D., it was applicable.  But not today.

Today, there are still sins to avoid, because all sin is to our destruction.  While momentary pleasure may be derived from sin, true fulfillment comes as we live in the presence of God.

So, wear whatever fabrics you want, but seek to know God.  That is what the Scriptures call us to today.

Comment: This answer would be improved by passages indicating that the new covenant is now in effect.